# Splitting up web services on different dedicated web servers

Tags: web-services, iis, networking

I currently have a number of web services on a single server.
In the future we want to move the load off a single server and split it to other servers.

I am familiar with the concept of scaling out but in our case I want to have different web services on different web servers so that traffic can be routed to the correct web services. So web services that do a lot more intensive work can be dedicated to a specific server.

How would I do this?

Would I need to change my client applications so that the correct webservice is called on the correct web server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the proper pattern to use here would be tho have one server with a dispatcher that will just forward requests to appropriate back-end services. Then if you decide to move one of back-end services to another server, then you can just make configuration change in the dispatcher.

I am sure you can do it programmatically, but I am sure software or hardware (like F5) load balancer have ability to configure it out.

Comment: Thank you sebastien for you input. I was not aware load balancers can filter to different servers based on calls. I thought they did just round robin type distribution.

Comment: They usually do more than that - the following from wikipedia describes the feature: Content-aware switching: most load balancers can send requests to different servers based on the URL being requested, assuming the request is not encrypted (HTTP) or if it is encrypted (via HTTPS) that the HTTPS request is terminated (decrypted) at the load balancer.